# Save stripe customer details for a project

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am working on a project where I have integrated stripe connect which is working fine, but now the problem is how I can check that returned details on redirect url are for a specific project.

Projects functions as follows.
1.Registered users add Non-Profit.
2.Connect to their stripe account to accept payments.

Stripe connect button has been placed on project addition page, users clicks on it and returned to a url (given in application) with connected users details, but on this page I have lost the project id for which user was connecting stripe account so I cant save it in database ( i assume that they needs to be saved in database to use at time of donation).

Am I doing something wrong ?
Is there any other way to get it done ?

I have used https://gist.github.com/amfeng/3507366 as reference.

Comment: Store the info in the session or use the `state` parameter when redirecting to the authorize URL: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/reference#get-authorize-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different code approaches and code samples available on net I found that we can use `state` parameter to get the respective id to which you want to connect the stripe account.

On my application iu `https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&scope=read_write&client_id=CLIENT_ID&state=705` where state is the user ID to connect with.

To open authorization window I used window popup and connect to stripe account by filling details after authorization popup window is closed and then I used $_GET to get user id and saved it in database.